# SwiftUI - How to modify textfield in an array

Tags: arrays, swiftui

**In the following code, which you can copy into a new SwiftUI project, when I run it and start typing into the textfield, the field loses focus after each character.  How can I fix this? I dont understand about observable objects so perhaps this is the problem? and BTW, I'm using Xcode 13.0 Beta 5**

```
struct CmdOption: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID { UUID() }
    var value: String
}

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var theOptions: [CmdOption] = [
        CmdOption(value: ""),
        CmdOption(value: "")
    ]
    
    @State var allOptions: [CmdOption] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                ForEach($allOptions, id: \.self)  { $option in
                    VStack {
                        TextField(option.value, text: $option.value)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            startup()
        }
    }
    func startup() {
        allOptions.removeAll()
        theOptions.forEach {option in
            allOptions.append(option)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You have `id` as a computed property. This means that is will change *every* time you try read the value.
2. You are using `id: \.self`, which is not unique (since `id` was also stored as a computed property, it isn't considered for default `Hashable` conformance).

To fix this, change `CmdOption` to the following:

```
struct CmdOption: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var value: String
}
```

And your `ForEach` (implicitly `id: \.id`):

```
ForEach($allOptions) { $option in
    VStack {
        TextField(option.value, text: $option.value)
    }
}
```

Now, these view's IDs are **constant** and **unique**. The `TextField`s will now no longer lose focus, because they aren't recreating the view every time `ContentView`'s body is recomputed, as their ID has remained the same. See [Demystify SwiftUI - WWDC21](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/) to learn more about how IDs affect a view's lifecycle.